# AUC and classification report in Logistic regression in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have been trying to implement logistic regression in python. Basically the code works and it gives the accuracy of the predictive model at a level of 91% but for some reason the AUC score is 0.5 which is basically the worst possible score because it means that the model is completely random. Also the classification report returns error: "UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. 'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)". Does anyone know what should I change so it works properly?

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score  
 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
 from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
 from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

 data_file = pd.read_csv('loan.csv', delimiter=',')

 # variable preprocessing

 data_file['loan_status'] = np.where(data_file['loan_status'].isin(['Fully 
 Paid', 'Current']), 1, 0)
 loan_stat=data_file['loan_status']
 loan_stat=loan_stat.astype(np.float64)

 m = {
    'n/a': 0,     
    '< 1 year': 0,
    '1 year': 1,
    '2 years': 2,
    '3 years': 3,
    '4 years': 4,
    '5 years': 5,
    '6 years': 6,
    '7 years': 7,
    '8 years': 8,
    '9 years': 9,
    '10+ years': 10
 }
 emp_length=data_file.emp_length.map(m)
 emp_length.astype(np.float64)

 annual_inc=data_file['annual_inc']
 delinq_2yrs=data_file['delinq_2yrs']
 dti=data_file['dti']
 loan_amnt=data_file['loan_amnt']
 installment=data_file['installment']
 int_rate=data_file['int_rate']
 total_acc=data_file['total_acc']
 open_acc=data_file['open_acc']
 pub_rec=data_file['pub_rec']
 acc_now_delinq=data_file['acc_now_delinq']

 #variables combined into one dataframe

 X=pd.DataFrame()

 X['annua_inc']=annual_inc
 X['delinq_2yrs']=delinq_2yrs
 X['dti']=dti
 X['emp_length']=emp_length
 X['loan_amnt']=loan_amnt
 X['installment']=installment
 X['int_rate']=int_rate
 X['total_acc']=total_acc
 X['open_acc']=open_acc
 X['pub_rec']=pub_rec
 X['acc_now_delinq']=acc_now_delinq
 X['loan_stat']=loan_stat

 X=X.dropna(axis=0)
 y=X['loan_stat']
 X=X.drop(['loan_stat'], axis=1)

 scaler=StandardScaler()
 X=scaler.fit_transform(X)

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
 random_state=42)

 model=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=1)
 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
 score=accuracy_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
 roc=roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
 cr=classification_report(y_test, model.predict(X_test))
```

Here is the link to the data: https://www.kaggle.com/wendykan/lending-club-loan-data/downloads/lending-club-loan-data.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to calculate the AUC, you need to have probabilities. Therefore you should use the following function:

```
roc=roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```

This will give you the probability for each sample in X_test having label 1.

Comment: It worked. thanks. but the classification report still returns the above mentioned error. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: Not sure, what does your y look like? Might be due to this if you're only predicting one class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757653/why-does-scikitlearn-says-f1-score-is-ill-defined-with-fn-bigger-than-0

Comment: my y is a vector of "1" and "0"

Comment: And your predictions, also both 1 and 0?

Comment: unfortunately predictions give me 1 for all samples. So does it mean that the report is correct? but the there are 600k samples in the set. it is very unlikely that all predictions would be 1

Comment: It means that the error is correct, in the sense that it cannot compute the precision and F-score if you only predict 1. Training on an imbalanced dataset might be the reason for this.

Comment: Are there any ways to deal with this? It is true that the set is imbalanced (class 1 is almost in 98% of cases). but are there any better metrics to asses binary imbalanced classifiers?

Comment: Yes, your dataset is definitely imbalanced. AUC is a metric which is robust to imbalancedness.